# Hazelcast distributed lock fairness

Tags: locking, hazelcast

Is there any way to achieve hazelcast distributed lock fairness? 
It doesn't support now. 
Please advise

Thankyou

Comment: Can you elaborate on your use case and what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

Hazelcast distributed `ILock`s do not support fairness as is stated in the docs. Blocking operations are put in wait set and picked up randomly, so it can be quite unfair in some situations.

Implementing fairness with distributed locks would decrease performance greatly. Even if it would satisfy your use-case, it might not meet your performance requirements.

In most of the situations Hazelcast `EntryProcessor` achieves what `ILock` would offer. It has a FIFO based work queue so processor requests going to the same partitions will be guaranteed to run in FIFO order.

Hazelcast has a variety of distributed data structures. I am sure with the right combination of usage, you can achieve fairness for your use case.

Comment: can you share an example with Entry Processor to achieve fairness